# Trigger.oldMap return error "Variable does not exist"

Tags: account, trigger-oldmap

I am writing a class using Trigger.oldmap to find old account ownerId but it does not recognize what OwnerId is.

`(Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id)).OwnerId`

The script is trying to create a custom "Assignment History" record whenever the Billing Postal Code in Account changes. This part of script look like this:

```
else if (Trigger.isUpdate){
                    Assignment_History__c newAH = new Assignment_History__c();
                    newAH.New_Owner__c          = acc.OwnerId;
                    newAH.New_Territory__c      = terNameOwnerToId.get(acc.BillingPostalCode + acc.OwnerId);
                    newAH.Account__c            = acc.Id;
                    newAH.Changed_by__c         = UserInfo.getUserId();
                    System.debug('Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id) is ' + Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id));
                    System.debug('Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).OwnerId is ' + (Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id)).OwnerId);
                    System.debug('newAH looks like this ' + newAH);
                    newAssignHistories.add(newAH);
                }
```

The error I am getting is:
Variable does not exist: OwnerId

I don't understand why OwnerId in the Trigger.oldMap is not recognized. Thank you in advance for explaining it.

The whole script is like this:

```
for (Account acc : accs) {
            
            if(acc.BillingPostalCode != null) {
                
           
                if (Trigger.isInsert){
                    Assignment_History__c newAH = new Assignment_History__c();
                    newAH.New_Owner__c          = acc.OwnerId;
                    newAH.New_Territory__c      = terNameOwnerToId.get(acc.BillingPostalCode + acc.OwnerId);
                    newAH.Account__c            = acc.Id;
                    newAH.Changed_by__c         = UserInfo.getUserId();
                    System.debug('newAH looks like this ' + newAH);
                    newAssignHistories.add(newAH);
                }
                else if (Trigger.isUpdate){
                    Assignment_History__c newAH = new Assignment_History__c();
                    newAH.New_Owner__c          = acc.OwnerId;
                    newAH.New_Territory__c      = terNameOwnerToId.get(acc.BillingPostalCode + acc.OwnerId);
                    newAH.Account__c            = acc.Id;
                    newAH.Changed_by__c         = UserInfo.getUserId();
                    System.debug('Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id) is ' + Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id));
                    System.debug('Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id).OwnerId is ' + (Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id)).OwnerId);
                    System.debug('newAH looks like this ' + newAH);
                    newAssignHistories.add(newAH);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of a `.trigger` file, `Trigger.old`, `Trigger.new`, `Trigger.oldMap`, and `Trigger.newMap` are generic `sObject` collections, so you can only access [sObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) methods, and the generic `Id` field.

You need to [cast](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_casting.htm) to the appropriate type before you can use actual fields:

```
newAH.New_Owner__c          = ((Account)acc).OwnerId;
```

It's this reason why developers recommend passing in a trigger variable:

```
public static void afterInsertHandler(Account[] newRecords) {
```

Which is then called from the trigger:

```
AccountTriggerHandler.afterInsertHandler(Trigger.new);
```

Comment: I am not familiar with "handler".  I am currently writing a class. Inside that class I have the actual "method" which is the script above. Do you mean within the same class, I should write another "handler" above the "method" code? Or the best practice would be to create a new separate class and have the above "handle"  written in that separate class? Btw I am on my first month coding, so I newbies. Thanks!

Comment: @FelixFong A handler is a class that holds the business logic for a trigger. See [this](https://github.com/trailheadapps/apex-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/classes/Shared%20Code/TriggerHandler.cls) for example. The best practice is indeed to have a class that handles the business logic for a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

```
Account oldAcc = (Account) Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.Id);
System.Debug(oldAcc.OwnerId);
```